# Is it necessary to unsubscribe

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am having hard time understanding RX. In the following case, is it necessary to unsubscribe? Is there a way to automatically unsubscribe after the "call" function was executed?

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<NumberInfo>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super NumberInfo> subscriber) {
            try {
                // Store data to db
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Downloaded numberInfo was not added to cache.", e);
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe();
```

I don't want to observe for any result that's why I omitted the classical `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`

Thx for explanation.

Comment: `I don't want to observe for any result` - then you don't need `Observable` in the first place. What problem you're trying to solve exactly?

Comment: @Dmitry Zaitsev I need it to replace asyncTask. The second option could be to run the snippet in a thread but the observable can handle it too.

Comment: I would consider using Async extensions for RxJava - they have all this stuff implemented already, so you can just call `start(yourTask).subscribe()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Rx contract, when the `Observable` fires `onCompleted`, the `Observer` unsubscribes. In your case, the contract is not respected because there is no `subscriber.onCompleted()` in your code.

If you just need something like "Fire and forget", you could try just:

```
Schedulers.io().createWorker().schedule(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        try {
            // Store data to db
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Downloaded numberInfo was not added to cache.", e);
        }
    }
});
```

It will execute on **I/O** Scheduler and your UI thread is safe.

IMO you should always have a return value. Your `Store data to db` routing surely has some return value, like a `long` specifying the row number or a `boolean` that indicates *success*. Having this approach, you can create a proper method:

```
public Observable<Long> storeToDb(final SomethingToStore storeMe) {
    return Observable
            .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> subscriber) {
                    long row = syncStore(storeMe);

                    if (row == -1) {
                        subscriber.onError(new Throwable("Cannot store " + storeMe.toString + " to DB."));
                    }

                    subscriber.onNext(row);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
storeToDb(storeThis)
        .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("STORING", "Something went south: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Long row) {
                Log.d("STORING", "Everything has been stored as record number: " + row);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

When Observable is complete, RxJava unsubscribes automatically. You need to call `subscriber.onComplete()` to perform automatic unsubscription.